# What Joomla specific problems am I likely to encounter when changing from apache to nginx?

Tags: cms, nginx, apache

I'm considering changing from apache to nginx, but I imagine it's going to be a pain.

I've read

- http://docs.joomla.org/Nginx
- http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs#Nginx

So far I haven't been able to find much information on problems associated with changing from apache to nginx.

**LIKELY PROBLEMS**

I know that I'll need to convert any apache rules to nginx format. I expect extensions that rely on .htaccess files will either not work or I will have to manually convert their rules to nginx.

- Are there any other Joomla related problems I'm likely to encounter
  when going from apache to nginx?
- Has anyone taken the nginx plunge for Joomla? Would you recommend doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already taken the "plunge" to nginx, and my findings:

- .htaccess rules are one of the main problems, but can be overcome by
  "translating" them to nginx configuration instructions (you can do
  them by hand, but there are some handy tools on the internet to help
  you convert them, like this one: [htaccess to nginx converter](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess))

  Note that in some cases having an .htaccess with certain rules (which
  nginx will ignore) will break the site! (nginx ignores it, but
  somehow it breaks it (giving an error 500)). This has not happened to
  the stock .htaccess from Joomla.
- Virtual hosts are managed in a different way (not really related to
  Joomla, but still important to know)
- It is indeed very fast! I compared to the same site with an Apache
  server.

Other than that I haven't found any other problems.

EDIT: some aditional input about the extensions:

- All the stock extensions work as expected
- The URL rewriting and SEO works as expected (as long as you define
  the rules in nginx)
- Other extensions work as expected, the ones I tested are:

  Akeeba Backup (latest); JCE (latest); Community Builder (latest);   Chronoforms (latest)
- Even my customized extensions (created by myself) work without any
  hickups!

This was with two sites (the technical details are Joomla 3.2.2, nginx/1.1.19, PHP 5.4.25 (FPM), mySQL 5.5.35, Ubuntu 12.04.4).

The bottom line is that in my tests and production sites, all is working fine and not that hard to set up and run, so go for it!